# spring boot and rabbitmq (AMQP 1.0) with TLS

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, tls1.2, spring-rabbit

I am looking for a spring boot sample with connection to rabbitmq (or general AMQP 1.0 server) via TLS1.2 ... possibly using some already available plugins.

Many thanks in advance for any help

Best Regards

Lukasz

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no AMQP 1.0 support in Spring, only 0.9.1 for RabbitMQ.

You can, of course, use something like the [Apache QPID Proton Client](http://qpid.apache.org/proton/index.html) in your boot application.

Comment: You can, of course, use something like the [Apache QPID Proton Client](http://qpid.apache.org/proton/index.html) in your boot application.

Comment: Thank you Gary. I found your post: https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-662. Two questions: - is there any sample you could share (btw. most probably we will have to talk to Azure service bus)? - does this support TLS 1.2? Thank in advance.

Comment: They changed the API shortly after I created that PoC; you will have to use their API directly; I haven't looked at it lately, I suggest you refer to their documentation, samples etc.

Comment: Thank you Gary! If possible we would like to avoid introducing another API (Azure ESB). I found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-jms-api-amqp which seems to confirm qpid to work, qpid jms client seems to be ready for TLS: https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-0.50.0/docs/index.html. If both are valid, do you think your PoC is still an option? If yes, can you share some details? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `>your PoC is still an option?` No; as I said, it was for QPID Proton AMQP 1.0 and they changed the API completely,shortly after I wrote my PoC. I believe it's been stable for a while, now, but I haven't done any work with it. The Proton JMS bridge together with Spring JMS should be a workable option.

Answer (score 0):

The [AMQP 1.0 JMS Spring Boot](https://github.com/amqphub/amqp-10-jms-spring-boot) library provides a spring boot starter that integrates the [Apache Qpid JMS Client](https://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/index.html) with Spring JMS. It seems to be actively maintained (in Jan 22)